# Going out of their way to look for דם בתולים the second time

Tags: halacha, niddah, inspection, blood

I know the p'sak of the Aruch HaShulchan, that you must check the sheets after the 2nd/3rd time a newly-married couple are intimate. I heard that there is a more lenient opinion that you don't even have to check the sheets at all. Where is the source for such an opinion (I heard maybe it was something Rav Moshe Feinstein said) and what is the explanation with regards to such a leniency?

Comment: Yosef Platt, thanks for your bringing your question to Mi Yodeya; welcome!  I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including for example [our forty-nine other _nida_ questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/niddah). Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: See Badei Hashulchan pg 29